# Emitting a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that I would like to emit as an argument.

I have tried the following:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['watch1', 'watch2'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
    if (scope.1 && scope.2) {
        $scope.$emit('enableButton', {$scope.submit(true)});
    }
});
```

Where $scope.submit(true) is a function I have defined in the current controller.

Then in my other controller:

```
$scope.$on('enableButton', function(event, data) {
  $scope.buttonAction = data;
});
```

When I try to assign $scope.buttonAction the function that was passed through as an argument, the function just automatically fires when the $emit occurs. Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you not getting an unexpected token error by any chance? `{$scope.submit(true)}` is invalid object syntax.

Comment: does `if (scope.1 && scope.2)` is ever possible..? variable name shouldn't start with number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are passing a function call with an argument and params, the function call is executed the moment you try to pass it in the event.  You should pass a *reference* to the function instead.

```
$scope.$emit('enableButton', $scope.submit);
```

If you need to preserve the argument, you can wrap your function call in an anonymous function and pass that function.  This is different than passing by reference and is often used for callback arguments:

```
$scope.$emit('enableButton', function() { return $scope.submit(true); });
```

The caveat here is that if you use a variable to represent true and that variable changes before `$scope.buttonAction` is called, the value passed will also change.

You can work around this in a modern browser by using `.bind()` to preserve the context of your variable.

```
$scope.$emit('enableButton', $scope.submit.bind(this, isSubmittable));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Essentially I have assigned a button that function, but it is not working on-click because (true) is not present. It is part of an ng-repeat if that makes any difference. Is it possible to pass it (true) in the parent controller?

Comment: @JordanMcRae glad to help.  I've updated my answer to include a way to preserve arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to update your answer. This was exactly what I was looking for.